# How to go to first screen in Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to delete all screens from stack in android auto app with

```
screenManager.popToRoot().
```

But when I use it, it says that I have reached the 5 screen limit of the stack.

For example, if I'm doing this flow:

1. Screen A
2. Screen B
3. Screen C
4. Screen D
5. Screen E

When I click on a button I created on screen E, I want to go back to Screen A and remove all stack.

Someone can tell me how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the log mentioning the 5 screen limit?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use popTo() method. you can set marker to your root screen.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/ScreenManager#popTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: did this solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it manually, instead of using

```
screenManager.popToRoot()
```

Use

```
startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, firstActivity.class))
finishAffinity()
```

Note that `finishAffinity` is used to finish all activities associated with the task, including all activities in the task's back stack. When `finishAffinity()` is called, the task's root activity and all activities below it in the back stack are finished.